# Внести небольшие изменения в маску телефона

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт маски телефона, у которого пара не совсем приятных моментов. Первый - это возможность удалить семерку. И второй - когда номер уже полностью набран, то при вводе уже лишней цифры, она вводится и тут же удаляется.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
function setCursorPosition(pos, elem) {
    elem.focus();
    if (elem.setSelectionRange) elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    else if (elem.createTextRange) {
        var range = elem.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd("character", pos);
        range.moveStart("character", pos);
        range.select()
    }
}

var is_del = false;
var is_back = false;
function mask(event) {
    var curent_position = -1;
    if(event.type == "keyup"){
      curent_position = this.selectionStart;
    }
    var matrix = "+7 (___) ___ ____",
        i = 0,
        def = matrix.replace(/\D/g, ""),
        val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
    if (def.length >= val.length) val = def;
    this.value = matrix.replace(/./g, function(a) {
        return /[_\d]/.test(a) && i <= val.length ? val.charAt(i++) : i < val.length ? a : i++ == 6 && val.length == 4 && event.keyCode !=8 && event.keyCode !='' ? ")" : ""
    });
    is_back = is_del = false;
    if(event.keyCode == 8) is_back = true;
    else if(event.keyCode == 46) is_del = true;
    if (event.type == "blur") {
        if (this.value.length == 2) this.value = "";
    } else if(curent_position != -1){
      if(is_del || is_back){
        setCursorPosition(curent_position, this);
      }
    } else if(event.type == "focus") setCursorPosition(this.value.length, this);
};
    var input = document.querySelector("#tel");
    input.addEventListener("focus", mask, false);
    input.addEventListener("blur", mask, false);
    input.addEventListener("keyup", mask, false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="tel">
```

Comment: Так, стоп.. Я где-то это уже видел...

Comment: Хватит велосипеды плодить, это очень плохо. Особенно в таких мелочах. Уже куча готовых решений. Например писали выше, или это http://js.nicdn.de/bootstrap/formhelpers/docs/phone.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так уже должно работать так как вы хотите.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    function setCursorPosition(pos, elem) {
        elem.focus();
        if (elem.setSelectionRange)
            elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
        else if (elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd("character", pos);
            range.moveStart("character", pos);
            range.select()
        }
    }

    var is_del = false;
    var is_back = false;
    var def_position = -1;
    function mask(event) {
        var curent_position = -1;
        if (event.type == "keyup") {
            curent_position = this.selectionStart;
        }
        var matrix = "+7 (___) ___ ____",
                i = 0,
                def = matrix.replace(/\D/g, ""),
                val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
        if (def.length >= val.length)
            val = def;
        if (event.type == "input") {
            if(this.value.charAt(0) !='+'){
              this.value = this.value.replace(/^(.{1})./, '$1+');
            }
            if(this.value.charAt(1) != '7'){
              this.value = this.value.replace(/^(.{2})./, '$17');
            }
            if (this.value.length < 2) {
                this.value = matrix.replace(/./g, function(a) {
                    return /[_\d]/.test(a) && i <= val.length ? val.charAt(i++) : i < val.length ? a : i++ == 6 && val.length == 4 && event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != '' ? ")" : ""
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            this.value = matrix.replace(/./g, function(a) {
                return /[_\d]/.test(a) && i <= val.length ? val.charAt(i++) : i < val.length ? a : i++ == 6 && val.length == 4 && event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != '' ? ")" : ""
            });
        }
        is_back = is_del = false;
        if (event.keyCode == 8)
            is_back = true;
        else if (event.keyCode == 46)
            is_del = true;
        if (event.type == "blur") {
            if (this.value.length == 2)
                this.value = "";
        } else if (curent_position != -1) {
            if (is_del || is_back) {
                setCursorPosition(curent_position, this);
            }
        } else if (event.type != "input")
            setCursorPosition(this.value.length, this);
    }
    ;
    var input = document.querySelector("#tel");
    input.addEventListener("focus", mask, false);
    input.addEventListener("blur", mask, false);
    input.addEventListener("keyup", mask, false);
    input.addEventListener("input", mask, false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxlength="17" id="tel">
```

Comment: @LADYX Вот так норм?

Comment: @LADYX нет опять возвращается, но если и это не устраивает попробую еще разобраться

Comment: @LADYX Обновил ответ. посмотрите

Comment: @LADYX не возможно, я на двух браузерах смотрел, и не удаляется не чем. Перезагрузите страницу потом посмотрите.

Comment: @LADYX Я только в опере не проверял, в остальных работает.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66881/discussion-between-razmik-galstyan-and-ladyx).

Comment: @LADYX Вот теперь понял о чем вы говорили, посмотрите сейчас ответ.

Comment: @LADYX Да но как я думаю для этого вообще нужно изменить логику вашу.

Answer (score 4):

Есть библиотека https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin, которая предоставляет маски для ввода. Добавляем свой хак, чтобы +7 нельзя было удалить и решение готово.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  $('#tel').mask('+7 (000) 000 0000');
  $('#tel').on('keypress, keydown', function(event) {
    var $field = $(this);
    var readOnlyLength = 2;

    if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39)) &&
      ((this.selectionStart < readOnlyLength) ||
        ((this.selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8)))) {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.12/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="tel" value="+7">
```